# can anyone help me with this simple (javascript) script

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart

I want to upgrade this simple script by javascript. It's just simple script that calculates the total from check-boxed services menu.

But right now it's just calculating and bring the total price and iI want to upgrade it so he can type the services that has been cheeked.

http://jsfiddle.net/tL5hdf64/1/

And the JS code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var totalprice = 0;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        totalprice= totalprice + parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $('#price').val(totalprice);
});
```

Comment: So what is your the question?

Comment: do you mean you want the user to be able to add their own service and price to your table and have it update the total price?

Comment: Its not clear what you want. Could you explain properly?

Comment: Unable to comprehend..Please explain

Comment: `so what i want is to upgrade this simple script by javascript ` Do  you want the same code in JavaScript?? Is that you question?

Comment: no no it's just i want the javascript code type the price and the services that has benn checked beside total price form .. that's it >> thanks a lot

Comment: Edited the question. **Keep your question short and concise**, make do without the unnecessary pleasantries and go straight to the point, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/tL5hdf64/3/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
var totalprice =0;
var serv = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    totalprice= totalprice + parseInt($(this).val());
    serv.push($(this).closest('tr').find('label').html()); 
});
$('#price').val(totalprice);
$('#services').html(serv);
});
```

Comment: a lot thanks man ... you make my day really .. best answer for sure ... thanks a lot again

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var totalprice =0;
     $(".services").html("");
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        totalprice= totalprice + parseInt($(this).val());
        $(".services").append($(this).parent().siblings().before().html() +"<br/>");
    });
    $('#price').val(totalprice);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tL5hdf64/4/